# Multiple values passed in query string

Tags: javascript, query-string

I am using something the below code to pass a single value via query string to my html page on button click using Javascript function.

```
window.location.href("somepage.html?w1=" + hello);
```

The above code is working fine.

But when I am trying to append second variable with this URL, nothing happens on click of the button.

```
window.location.href("somepage.html?w1=" + hello + "&w2=" + world);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is `world` a defined variable?

Comment: It's `window.location.href = "somepage.html?w1="+ hello +"&w2="+ world;` I.e. your "first code" is not working (I tested it and got "string is not a function").

Comment: `window.location.href`is not a function. There is no way that'll work.

Comment: @Brian World and Hello are strings, not variables

Comment: But it is working for single values. Also, I have tried using window.location.href="something/html?....." for passing multiple values. It dint work either. Nothing happens on button click

Comment: @ArpitaDutta The way your code is written, hello and world are variable references, not string literals.

Answer (score 1):

href is a property. try assigning the value like this:

```
window.location.href = "somepage.html?w1=" + hello + "&w2=" + world;
```